Convert WKT2 to proj4 with axis conversion
I need to find a solution to transform WKT2 to proj4, including the axis definition. for example iI have this EPSG:2389
I get the WKT like this:
PROJCS["Xian 1980 / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger CM 132E",GEOGCS["Xian 1980",DATUM["Xian_1980",SPHEROID["IAG 1975",6378140,298.257,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7049"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6610"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4610"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",132],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","2389"]]
converting it using pycrs I get this proj4 string in return:
+proj=utm +a=6378140.0 +rf=298.257 +pm=0 +lat_0=0.0 +lon_0=132.0 +x_0=500000.0 +y_0=0.0 +units=m +axis=enu +no_defs
it does look promising, since it has the +axis=enu I was expecting it to have.
converting the same string using gdalsrsinfo, I get this:
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +no_defs
Strangely completely different, and with also completely different outputs when using it with proj4.
Interestingly enough, there is a third alternative for this EPSG:
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +towgs84=26,-121,-78,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
from here
which also generates a completely different output.
I am doing the whole thing, because the mapnik definition misses the axis definition in the proj4 string. so i need to generate it myself to have the correct definition.
But how?
What am I missing here when converting it?
https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2389/

Proj 9.5.0 gives projinfo epsg:2389 PROJ.4 string: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=132 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=IAU76 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
